# .htaccess friendly url for a social networking site

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to make a small social networking site..
I want to make member's profile url SEO friendly 
Like Facebook

If the url is

```
http://localhost/keralap/johny.abc
```

The content should be from

```
http://localhost/keralap/member.php?userismnob=johny.abc
```

And I need Options -Indexes also..
I tried .. But not working..

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ /member.php?userismnob=$1
```

I am a 15 year old boy, So sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

must check johny.abc is not a real file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ member.php?userismnob=$1 [L]
```

P.S. also forward slash is not needed for the member.php in `/keralap/` context, as it would mean `document_root/member.php`

Answer (score 0):

You are matching the full url in your rewrite rule, try this instead:

```
RewriteBase /keralap
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /member.php?userismnob=$1
```

`RewriteBase` is because I imagine you're running your site from the `keralap` subdirectory.

Comment: It is not working,,
**Remember**
.htaccess is contained in the folder **keralap** .. and localhost/keralap/ is my home page
and it is **keralap** not **keralab**

Comment: What about without the `RewriteBase` ?